# Looking for a solution to make my progressbars only visible when they are active

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a small WPF window which contains timers.
These are made with a label(for the countdown) on top of a progressbar.

Though i would like to make these only visible when they are counting down.

I am thinking i got 2 choices.
Either make them invisible as soon as they hit 0.
Or check if they contain data(saved in a xml file), if so make it visible if not invisible.

Honestly i am very new to WPF, so half the time i still doing thing that just don't work in WPF.

But would like some input on my best options for this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? Usually you would be using MVVM and just add an `IsBusy` property to the view model and use a value converter to determine visibility based on binding to the property. What have you got so far?

Comment: To be honest i have not added any code yet for this.
Since i was unsure what direction to go with this.
And wanted to get some ideas what to do with it.

Comment: Are you using an MVVM approach or do you just have code behind your forms?

Comment: Just got code behind the forms.